# 'I don't know WHOM he is' or 'I don't know WHO he is'?

Tags: pronouns, objects

> I don't know who(m) he is.

I'm trying to figure out if I should use 'who' or 'whom' in the sentence above. I'm attempting to reach a conclusion by identifying the deep structure, but I'm not sure what it would be. Ideally an answer would include a syntactic tree.

Comment: See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Ideally we'd be doing your homework for you.

Comment: @Paregon My answer below is correct, and you will find comparable explanations in all American language arts textbooks. Standardized English comprehension tests include questions that require you to know the distinction between subject and object pronouns, including the much denounced (see below) "whom," which you may use at any level of society without fear of mockery, despite the raised eyebrows of a few ELU gamers.

Comment: I’m not a student, nor is this homework

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the syntactic tree, but "who" would be the correct pronoun. The clause that governs is "Who he is?," which could also be written "Who is he?, and "He is who?" The verb "is" (to be) is a linking verb. With linking verbs, the object is the same case as the subject (not the object case: whom). "Whom did you bring?"uses the object pronoun because "to do" is not a linking verb.

Comment: This does not describe modern English as anyone knows it. Nobody in their right mind consistently uses the nominative after a so-called 'linking' verb. If someone calls out "Who's there?" would you normaly reply "It's I" or "It's me"?

Comment: And "Whom did you bring?" may have been the accepted version 50 years ago, but would get you some very strange looks in most conversations nowadays.

Comment: @Araucaria As you certainly know, English is constantly changing. The sophistication of last month is this month's naivete. The question that was asked five years ago on ELU, if asked today, even if the exact same words were used, would be a different question and no doubt prompt a different answer, though even the same answer  would be different in the context of ever-changing, ever-shifting English. You have admitted that someone in their right mind would use the nominative (Go out into crowd and listen. Scan your blog.). No one does anything consistently.

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, every Big K'r on ELU knows their Latin, but American textbooks use "linking" to explain the concept. Actually, "Tis I," has become fashionable among millenials, especially young Brits in stalls.

Comment: @Zan700 Are you suggesting that we dish out advice that "*With linking verbs, the object is the same case as the subject not the object case*"?

Comment: @Araucaria. I don't care what advice you dish out. My answer to the poster's question reflects how American Language Arts textbooks explain the concept (although there will usually be an escape clause). Certainly. the poster now knows what pronoun to use in his construction. Despite Lord Ashworth's chortling, whom still surfaces now and then, even on standardized tests. There's also literature to consider. For Who the Bell Tolls?

Comment: @Araucaria I'd like to note that "whom" and other pronouns that have fallen out of spoken fashion are largely adhered to in contemporary legal documents. So if you want to enter law or simply understand your credit card company's responsibilities, you could do worse than understand the distinction between who and whom, and the role that linking verbs play. https://www.sfbar.org/basf-bulletin/2012/may-2012/legal-writing-tip-who-whom.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the discussion :)